# Calculate time difference from MySQL time

Tags: mysql

I am using the following call in my query to calculate the amount of time between now and a timestamp:

```
(NOW() - bu.banusr_expire)
```

bu.banusr_expire is a TIMESTAMP field.

I'm a little confused about the number it is returning.
ex; it returns -928 when there is about a 9.5 minute difference.

This makes me think that -928 = -9mins and 28 seconds(or 15 seconds. This set of digits seems to go from 0-99), but that seems completely wrong.

My question is, how can this value be converted to minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(bu.banusr_expire)) / 60
```

should give you the number of minutes ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you can be confident that the difference between the two times will always be less than 839 hours, then you can use [TIMEDIFF()](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,124334,124334).

Answer (score 0):

use unix timestamp

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(fieldname)
```

this will give you the diff in seconds you will have to divide by 60 for minutes